# How to recursively call a program in LabVIEW?

Tags: labview

I'm trying to get better at LabVIEW and as such I'm trying to write a program that takes in a string (in English) and outputs the result in Morse code. In python I would just use a dictionary with key value pairs, but I'm unsure if how to do it in LabVIEW. I figured out how to split a string into the first letter and the rest and was thinking of just having the entire alphabet with key value pairs inside one large case diagram, but I'm unsure of how to recursively call the via with the substring as the input (see block diagram)[image: block diagram]

I used the flat sequence structure to make sure that the case diagram acts before you recursively call the function, but I'm unsure if it's even necessary. Thanks for any help!

Comment: I think what you might be meaning is 'Repetition' rather than 'Recursion'. Recursion is calling code inside itself, Repetition is calling code repeatedly.

Comment: @Steve Actually, in Python, it would be a recursive function call. LabVIEW provides the iteration structure "For Loop" that achieves the same effect.

Comment: One little "gotcha" in LabVIEW recursion (which is certainly possible) is that you have to save the VI to file before you can call it in itself.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the 'FOR' Loop:
[image: For Loop operating on Morse Code Generation]

This is found in the 'Structures' device list, and additional information can be found [here](https://www.ni.com/en-us/support/documentation/supplemental/08/labview-for-loops-and-while-loops-explained.html)

Comment: So if I understand the for loop correctly, you wired empty string constant to a shift register to signal when the the loop should end? What exactly does a shift register signify in general if you don't mind me asking? I'm assuming for the convert to Morse section a case diagram with the 25 cases (for the alphabet) would work? Thanks so much! Edit: Additionally, what is the object to the left of the for loop connected to N and the original message? Thanks!

Comment: Your general understanding is correct. The symbol between the string and the N is 'String Length', essentially getting the size of the FOR loop to determine when it has parsed all the characters in the string. And the 'convert to morse would be a VI that takes in the character and passes out the appropriate morse value.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above 'Repetition' method of solving this problem, I thought I would demo a 'Recursive' solution.

In the following VI, the "RecurseString" subVI is the same VI being called from within itself. The string splitting and length is handled simply, with the remaining length checked to determine if the VI needs to be run again.
Depth is added as a check of the source code if/when you want handle infinite loop failover cases.

[image: Recursive Morse String build]

The big point for LabVIEW recursion is that you have to change the VI properties so that it is uses 'Shared Clone Re-Entrant Execution' from the VI Properties (*Ctrl + I > Execution*) otherwise it performs as expected from any other language.